# Excel Return location match/matches in a radius

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, latitude-longitude

For the past day now I have been working on a solution to return locations that fall within a 1/4 mile and 1/2 mile radius of a specific site. There is a list of about 3,000 sites that would need to be bounced off a portfolio (10,000+ locations) to see if they fell within a 1/4 mile and 1/2 mile radius of a location/locations in the portfolio. All the location data is Decimal Degrees format. In order to get things working properly first, I made a small mock data set to work with. A link to google drive to download that workbook is below. So far I have been able to get a site to return the closest match from the portfolio and the distance the site is from the portfolio match. However, in the real dataset along with the test data set, there may be more than one match from the portfolio. What do is needed to be done in order for each site to list the match/matches from the portfolio that fall in a 1/4 mile and 1/2 mile radius?

**Site List**

[image: Site List Screenshot]

**Portfolio**

[image: Portfolio Screenshot]

Distance formula

```
=INDEX(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Portfolio!$C$2:$C$6)) *COS(RADIANS(90-C2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-Portfolio!$C$2:$C$6)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-C2)) *COS(RADIANS(Portfolio!$D$2:$D$6-D2)))*3958.756,MATCH(SMALL((ABS(C2-Portfolio!$C$2:$C$6)^2+ABS(D2-Portfolio!$D$2:$D$6)^2)^(0.5),1),(ABS(C2-Portfolio!$C$2:$C$6)^2+ABS(D2-Portfolio!$D$2:$D$6)^2)^(0.5),0))
```

Nearest Location Formula

```
=INDEX(Portfolio!$A$2:$A$6,MATCH(SMALL((ABS(C2-Portfolio!$C$2:$C$6)^2+ABS(D2-Portfolio!$D$2:$D$6)^2)^(0.5),1),(ABS(C2-Portfolio!$C$2:$C$6)^2+ABS(D2-Portfolio!$D$2:$D$6)^2)^(0.5),0))
```

Google Drive Link

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eaDyUrjGjonV6iJkMa1Tac2v6NfquIsx
```

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle checkmark to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Bring the two tables into powerquery using data ... from table/range [x] headers.  Save one query as Portfolio, and use code below for a second query, Sites, by pasting into home ... advanced editor ... It will generate a complete list of distances from each Site to each Portfolio, then you could filter as you want it. Change 3959 to 6373 for Kilometers

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Site ID", type text}, {"Site Name", type text}, {"Latitude", type number}, {"Longitude", type number}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Portfolio),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Site ID", "Site Name", "Latitude", "Longitude"}, {"Portfolio.Site ID", "Portfolio.Site Name", "Portfolio.Latitude", "Portfolio.Longitude"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Distance", each Number.Acos(Number.Sin(([Latitude] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Sin(([Portfolio.Latitude] / 180) * Number.PI) + Number.Cos(([Latitude] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos(([Portfolio.Latitude] / 180) * Number.PI) * Number.Cos( ([Portfolio.Longitude] / 180) * Number.PI-([Longitude] / 180) * Number.PI)) * 3959)
in #"Added Custom1"
```

[image]

Note 3000 locations x 10000 portfolio sites = 30 million records, this is going to take a while. I would see how you could cut that down some as a pre-step